# How to use a String outside onCreate method

Tags: string, methods

I have the following code in my onCreate method:

```
Bundle appleData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(appleData==null) {
        return;
    }
    String appleMessage = appleData.getString("appleMessage");

    final TextView texttest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texttest);
    texttest.setText(appleMessage);
```

I want to use the string stored in appleMessage in a different method on the same activity that is outside of onCreate, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Just declare the String variable outside the onCreate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare a String attribute outside of the onCreate method. For example:

```
private String appleMessage;
```

Then, inside your onCreate, simply change this line:

```
appleMessage = appleData.getString("appleMessage");
```

When you want to use it on other method, just call it. Its value will be the value setted on the onCreated method.

Comment: You made it very simple, thanks @cristianorbs. I'll vote you up when my rank is high enough!

Comment: @Antonio simple isn't always better. If you only need it in one other method then making it a member variable isn't needed. You can simply pass it to the method you need. You should go through the Java docs and read about scope. Anyway, you don't have to wait to vote up, you can accept the answer that was most helpful by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @codeMagic i'll have a look through the docs.

Answer (score 3):

If you need it in several places in the class then you can make it a member variable by declaring it outside of a method

```
public class SomeClass extends Activity {

    String appleMessage = "default text";
```

but if you only need it in one method you can simply pass it to the method call if you are calling the method in `onCreate()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   ...
   String appleMessage = appleData.getString("appleMessage");

   final TextView texttest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texttest);
   texttest.setText(appleMessage);

   // here
   myMethod(appleMessage);
}
```

assuming `myMethod` takes a `String` as a parameter.

I also suggest you [read the java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and some basic tutorials before continuing with Android. It will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Create a member variable on the class, which is set inside the `onCreate` method.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) for more information on instance/member variables.

So:

```
class SomeClass extends Activity {
    private String appleMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        appleMessage = ...
    }

    public void otherMethod() {
        Log.e("LOG", "Here is appleMessage: " + appleMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare it inside your class and no in the method.

e.g.

```
private String appleMessage;
```

and use getters and setters for it

```
public String getAppleMessage(){
 return appleMessage;
}
```

Comment: Why getters and setters?